# MS Access - counting the number of check boxes

Tags: ms-access, checkbox

I am creating a basic database to monitor the status of paper forms - to basically say whether the form has been approved or if it is unapproved.

My table has a Module field and then a checkbox for 'Approved' and a checkbox for 'Unapproved'. Several forms can be submitted for each module.

For example, module 1 has several records in the table, several of these records have been ticked 'approved' and several others have been ticked 'unapproved'.

What I would like to do is have a report that groups each module and then displays the total number of approved and unapproved records for those modules.

I have tried using a textbox with

```
=Sum(IIf([Sem_Approved]=True,1,0))
```

but this just counts the total number of records that are approved. Not the total per module. Help appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at a totals Σ query grouped by module. Remember that a YesNo data type is equal to -1 when true and 0 when false. Consider Abs.

Comment: You're going to need to group your report by Module.  In the same menu where you set your Sort field, you can set your Group fields.  Add the Module field as a Group field, and that formula will sum by Module.